# Can Employer file case if by mistake employee down load source code

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, employer-relations, legal, intellectual-property

I am working as an software developer for startup IT software company.Company given me public access on all project source code .There is an download zip option on system on which by mistake I have clicked on while checking some project history while accessing project website using personal mobile. But I have deleted that one immediately

What would be best option to let my boss/HR know about this so that I will not be any legal trouble ..Is it legal to file any kind of legal case for employee

Comment: Are you allowed to have access to the source code from your personal mobile?  If so, why do you think it is a problem that you clicked that link?

Comment: There are no official email regarding permission but whole company is accessing project from mobile and management already knows it..because whole project depends on me in this startup company and my manager don't want that I will leave this company until unless they will get success..they are too much afraid with competitors ...but I already worked with them 2.8 years and now deciding to go back home country...That is only reason I wish to get to know about legality ...

Comment: It sounds like the company already expects that you can access it from your mobile, so I fail to see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Last thing, there is one employee who is spreading rumors in company that I will join their competitor in my home country or I will make my own software...that't is another reason because of that sometime I am afraid ....Do I need to talk with my HR and immediate line manger

Comment: Hi, Andy. I agree with Brandin. Meanwhile, do you think it would cause a bigger problem if you spoke to your HR and immediate line manager about this? And last thing, you may want to consider adding your other reason into your original question or posting it as a separate question. If the comments get too chatty here, they often get moved into chats :/. 
Welcome to The Workplace :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be best option to let my boss/HR know about this so that I
>   will not be any legal trouble.

It's unlikely you will be in any trouble over a simple mistake like this.

But the simplest way to avoid the possibility of any trouble is to talk to your boss now. Something like "Hey, boss. I accidentally downloaded some source code by mistake. I deleted the download as soon as I realized. Is there anything else I should do?" should suffice.

If you are really that worried, you might want to capture the discussion via email, so that you'll have a trail of question and reply.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you say "Last thing, there is one employee who is spreading rumors in company that I will join their competitor in my home country or I will make my own software...that't is another reason because of that sometime I am afraid ....Do I need to talk with my HR and immediate line manager"

Assuming that neither is the truth: That's something that is absolutely unacceptable. You should talk to your line manager, confirm that neither of these rumours are true, and ask him to stop that employee from spreading rumors. If talking to your line manager doesn't help, talk to HR.